# How to combine switch statements in MapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add these two filters to my Todo list:

```
const getVisibleList = (list, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL:
      return list
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_COMPLETED:
      return list.filter(t => t.completed)
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ACTIVE:
      return list.filter(t => !t.completed)
    default:
      throw new Error('Unknown filter: ' + filter)
  }
}

const getCategoryList = (list, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case CategoryFilters.SHOW_ALL:
      return list
    case CategoryFilters.SHOW_FAMILY:
      return list.filter(t => t.category === 'Family')
    case CategoryFilters.SHOW_PERSONAL:
      return list.filter(t => t.category === 'Personal')
    case CategoryFilters.SHOW_TRAVEL:
      return list.filter(t => t.category === 'Travel')
    case CategoryFilters.SHOW_WORK:
      return list.filter(t => t.category === 'Work')
    default:
      throw new Error('Unknown filter: ' + filter)
  }
}
```

How do I combine them to both work properly in `mapStateToProps`?

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  list: getVisibleList(state.list, state.visibilityFilter)
  //list: getCategoryList(state.list, state.categoryFilter)
})
```

I'm following [the Todolist example](https://redux.js.org/basics/example/) from the Redux website.

Comment: Those aren't reducers, and this isn't specific to React or Redux, but: `getCategoryList(getVisibleList(state.list, state.visibilityFilter), state.categoryFilter)`?

Comment: These are just the filters. You can use these in your `render` method to get the appropriate results.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you a lot, it worked. Oh ok I get it now, it's just javascript